# How to make footer text in center with two images on the right with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I need bit of help with footer on my page. I want to have text in footer in center with two images on the right side of the footer. Thank you in advance.

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEiza.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="CopyRightFooter">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8">
    <p class="text-center FooterText text-md-center">©Copyright</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 ml-lg-0">
    <div class="text-md-center">
      <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/instagram.png" class="footerImg" alt="Ig"> </a> </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fb.png" class="footerImg" alt="Fb"> </a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! If you are using bootstrap, just add the class `align-item-center` to the parent `.row` class.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck right now https://imgur.com/a/vkTZF2S . Text is aligned in it's own sqare but it's not aligned compared to the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.row {
  background: #2f405a;
}

.FooterText,
.social-links ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.social-links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* to center social links */
  align-items: center;
  /* to vertically center the text */
  justify-content: center;
  /* to horizontally center the text */
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .FooterText {
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 90px;
    /* width of social links */
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row position-relative">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="text-center FooterText text-md-center">©Copyright Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 ml-lg-0 social-links">
    <div class="text-center">
      <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a>
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/instagram.png" class="footerImg" alt="Ig">
                        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-inline-item">
          <a>
                            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fb.png" class="footerImg" alt="Fb">
                        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You've to use media queries.

```css
    @media only screen and (min-width:767px) { /* You can change width as you required */
.social-links {
position: absolute;
right:0;
width: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row position-relative">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="text-center FooterText text-md-center">©Copyright</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 ml-lg-0 social-links">
    <div class="text-center">
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/instagram.png" class="footerImg" alt="Ig">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-inline-item">
                <a>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fb.png" class="footerImg" alt="Fb">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work with text, but there is still large empty space between two icons. Also, when screen width is smaller than 992px I loose icons.

Comment: Yes, unless it's on mobile, then I would prefer them at the top of that copyright text.

Comment: changed the snippet. Please check once.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or what is it. Here are screenshots of my footer https://imgur.com/a/zjhHy0g .

Comment: Do you have any width to the social media icons (instagram and fb)?

Comment: Yes since original size is quite large.

Comment: You can give width to social-links in css as you required. Like .social-links img {width: 30px; height: auto;}

Comment: Try this and let me know if the requirement is done or not. So that I can help you.

Comment: Yes oh god thank you so much. I would just ask for one more thing. When width of screen is smaller than 767px, text gets covered with icons. Is there easy way to set icons above text?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for this?

Comment: Sure here it is. I added more text to that "Copyright" because friend wants it. Anyway, here it is https://imgur.com/a/ZoIwBNi

Comment: I think image is not there in the above link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got some error while uploading but image was still there. Should be now https://imgur.com/a/ZoIwBNi

Comment: I add a new snippet. please check

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I think you can do something like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <p>©Copyright</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col pr-5 text-right">
      <a>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/instagram.png" class="pr-2" alt="Ig">
      </a>
      <a>
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/fb.png" class="pl-2" alt="Fb">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Say me if this is enough for you.

Comment: How can I move icons more to the right and less apart? They also disappear on mobile. I'm sorry for being picky and thank you :)

Comment: I made a change to put the icons more apart, you can try use col-md, col-lg to test make some changes to adapt for mobile screens.